# How to perform operations like sin over Qiskit parameters

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit

I want to create a parameter dependent gate in qiskit and I need to compute some complex operations as `sympy.atan2` or `sympy.sin` over the parameters but I don't know how

I've tried

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
import sympy as sy
x=Parameter('x')
theta=Parameter('θ')
phase=sy.atan2(sy.N(x)*sy.sin(theta),sy.cos(theta))
circuit = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
circuit.cu1(phase,0,1)
```

but I obtain

```
CircuitError: 'invalid param type atan2 in instruction cu1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported in qiskit-terra yet with parametrized circuits. There is an open issue to add support for adding a parameter sweep with trig functions here:

https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/3908

Answer (score 0):

I think these gates only accept `float` or `np.float` as a parameter. Try casting to one of these types, for example `phase = float(phase)` and it should work.